# How do we use "면에서"?

Tags: vocabulary

Can '면에서' be used as a direct translation and be used in all contexts? 'In terms of..' is quite flexible and can be used in a lot of different contexts. But is it the same for '면에서'? When and how do Koreans use it?

I just found out about this website. Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

'면에서' literally is translated to 'in view of', 'in the aspect of ~' (but in the meaning, 'in terms of' too)
let me give you some examples.
그는 나이가 많다는 면에서 그 경쟁에서 불리하다. "In viewpoint that he is old, he has a disadvantage in the competition". here, 면에서 means a reason. I don't think we cannot say `In terms of the fact he is old` here.
If we really want to use `in terms of`, we could say
그는 나이 면에서 그 경쟁에서 불리하다. (In terms of age, he as a disadvantage in the competition)
I don't know if I explained it 100% right, but it's almost correct.