# Speaking about concerns with one's employment

Tags: translation, written

I am trying to make it a habit of writing/typing Korean. Could you see if the following makes sense and perhaps help me correct and make sound more natural?

내가 성인 돼 버렸다. 2018년 7월 23일은 내 졸업식이었는데도 내 마음 속에서 기쁘지 않았다. 4년동안 고생하고 원래는 우리 부모님들이 오래 살기 위해 돈을 많이 벌 수 있는 직장에서 일을 하기로 마음먹었는데, 취업사장에서 구해보니까 나에게 잘 어울리는 직업을 못 찾았다. 그래서 일단은 시카고에서 생활할 수 있도록 내가 하고 싶은 직업대신, 알바를 하거나 평범한 일을 구하기 시작했다. 
사람들이 대학교는 자기개발에 많이 집중할 수 있는 곳이라고 생각하는데 나는 우리 대학교에 있는 자기개발 기회들을 이용을 못 해서 내 개인적인 문제들이 많다고 깨닫았다.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Just for future reference (& as per https://korean.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) this site is more for specific questions, like your other question [here](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/4801/how-do-we-use-면에서) rather than more general requests such as proofreading.

Comment: Every grammatical marker gives slight weight to the word it got. Since you're to emphasize _what you became_, to say you're now a _grown-up_, it's natural not to skip the “`이`”: “`(내가) 성인이 되어 버렸다.`,” “`(내가) 성인이 돼 버렸다.`”

Comment: 전체적으로 무슨말을 전하려는지는 잘 이해가 갑니다. 하지만 부자연스러운 부분이 많이 보입니다.

Comment: It is incorrect to wirte "이용을 못 해서" since there is a verb "이용하다." We don't say "이용을 하다." So "이용하지 못해서" is a better expression.

Comment: I don't understand what "우리 부모님들이 오래 살기 위해" means. What is the original sentence?

Comment: @J1U “`이용`” is a noun, so technically that's **not** _incorrect_, yet wouldn't be a good (recommended) practice for this case here where the writer can just cannot-negate the verb form “`이용하다`.” Actually Korean often split `-하다` verbs up: “말이 통하지 않는 사람은 이쪽 말이 제대로 전달되었는지 저쪽 말이 정녕 바르게 통역되었는지 알 수 없어 갑갑하고 **답답만 했다.**” (from 한무숙's “만남”)

Comment: No, it is gramatically incorrect. "답답만 했다" do work because "-만" is a 보조사 which changes the meaning, but "이용을 했다" does not work because "-을" does not give any meaning. Similarly "사용을 했다" "공격을 했다" "생활을 했다" are all wrong, and they should be corrected as "사용했다" "공격했다" "생활했다."

Comment: @J1U It's all about different expressions; just because they means the same does not mean only one of them is _right_. “`바다 싸움에서 이겨 내지 못하는 한 너는 이 전쟁의 성패를 말할 수 없고, 조선 왕자를 붙들어 온다고 호언장담을 못 할 것이다.`” (“임진왜란”, 박종화.) ― should we correct this into “`못 호언장담할 것이다`” just because we have a verb “`호언장담하다`?”

Comment: @J1U We can say either “`답을 하시오.` (Do answering.)” or “`답하시오.` (Answer.)” and [both are total fine in Korean](http://www.korean.go.kr/front/mcfaq/mcfaqView.do?mcfaq_seq=2836) because the noun “`답`” means “`부르는 말에 응하여 어떤 말을 함` (answering).”

Comment: @J1U We can apply the “`……을(를) 하다`” form to behavioral nouns (동작성을 가진 명사), such as “`사용`”, “`이용`”, “`공격`”, “`답`” and “`생활`.” [국립국어원 (NIKL)'s aware of this kind of sentence structure and never has it ever said that this is grammatically wrong.](http://www.korean.go.kr/nkview/nknews/200208/49_2.html) The only case that this doesn't work is those weren't derived from behavioral nouns, like “`변하다`.”

Comment: It is technically right, but it is totally awkward to write in that way. If one is writing essay, s/he must avoid that kind of expressions.

Comment: @J1U Mm-hmm. Though, just speaking of my personal thought, a _must_ sounds a rather strong remark to me, no doubt that “`이용하지 못해서`” is the best sounding among the possible structures to express inability, “`못 이용해서`,” “`이용을 못 해서`,” and “`이용하지 못해서`.” I just get a bit pedantic when it comes to grammatical correctness. Please excuse me for that.

Answer (score 4):

내가 성인 돼 버렸다.

=> 나는 이제 성인이다.

2018년 7월 23일은 내 졸업식이었는데도 내 마음
속에서 기쁘지 않았다.

=> 2018년 7월 23일 내 졸업식 날, 마음 속에서부터 기쁘지는 않았다.

4년동안 고생하고 원래는 우리 부모님들이 오래 살기 위해 돈을 많이 벌
수 있는 직장에서 일을 하기로 마음먹었는데, 취업사장에서 구해보니까
나에게 잘 어울리는 직업을 못 찾았다.

=> 4년동안 고생하고, 원래는 우리 부모님들과 함께 오래 살기 위해 돈을
많이 벌 수 있는 직장에서 일을 하기로 마음먹었는데, 취업시장에서
나에게 잘 어울리는 직업을 찾지 못했다.

@ 그래서 일단은 시카고에서 생활할 수 있도록 내가 하고 싶은 직업대신,
알바를 하거나 평범한 일을 구하기 시작했다.

(Andrew Han's edit : This sentence is appropriate)

=> 그래서 일단 시카고에서 생활할 수 있도록 내가 하고 싶은 직업대신,
알바를 하거나 평범한 일을 하기로 결정했다.

@@ 사람들이 대학교는 자기개발에 많이 집중할 수 있는 곳이라고 생각하는데
나는 우리 대학교에 있는 자기개발 기회들을 이용을 못 해서 내 개인적인
문제들이 많다고 깨닫았다.

(Andrew Han's edit : 사람들은 보통 대학교**에서** 자기개발에 집중할 수 있다고 생각한다. 하지만 나는 우리 대학교가 제공하는 자기개발 기회들을 잘 이용하지 못해서 내 스스로 문제가 많다고 생각했다.)

=>사람들은 보통 대학교는 자기개발에 많이 집중할 수 있는 곳이라고
생각하는데, 대학교가 제공하는 자기개발 기회들을 얼마나 잘
활용하느냐에 달린 것 같다.

Comment: I think that Andrew Han's edit is more closer to a direct translation of OP's writing.